# Redux form with redux thunk SubmissionError

Tags: redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

I'm trying to use the `onSubmitSuccess` and `onSubmitFail` functionality in redux forms.

Previously i've dispatched actions such as reset the form, close the modal etc from a thunk (depending on the API response), but would like to utilise throwing SubmissionError's along with onSubmitSuccess/onSubmitFailure to call these actions from my component instead.

When throwing a SubmissionError from my Thunk, I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SubmissionError {errors: Object, message:
>   "Submit Validation Failed", name: "SubmissionError", stack:
>   "SubmissionError: Submit Validation Failed

Is there a good way to use Redux Form and Thunk together?

Comment: Please post your code; without it you will just leave people guessing what the problem might be.